# C Just add New Line to NULL point that cause segmentation fault for printf

Tags: c

I have a question that the segmentation fault was caused by just adding a new line to print. I use clang instead of gcc, Ubuntu 18.

What principles are hiding?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int     main(void)
{
    char            *newLineLocation = NULL;

    printf("%s \n", newLineLocation);
    printf("%s\n", newLineLocation);
    return (0);
}
```

---

Output:

```
holee@DESKTOP-GCFUM3M:~/hochan$ ./a.out 
(null) 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: undefined behaviour is undefined